# Assignment about calculating GPAs

Tags: c++

I have an assignment to calculate grades in the form of a GPA. The lecturer inputs four grades (0-100), then we convert them into letter grades and a GPA (0-4), then we average the GPA to finally print whether they failed.

I get the first half, but I have no idea how to average out the GPAs.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void convert()
{
    {
    int score;
    char letterGrade, numberGrade;
    
    cout << "Please enter a score." << endl;
    cin >> score;
    
    if (score<0 || score > 100)
    {
        cout << "Test scores must be between 1-100. " << endl;
    }
    else if (score < 50)
    {
        letterGrade = 'E';
        numberGrade = '0';
    }
    else if (score < 60)
    {
        letterGrade = 'D';
        numberGrade = '1';
    }
    else if (score < 70)
    {
        letterGrade = 'C';
        numberGrade = '2';
    }
    else if (score < 80)
    {
        letterGrade = 'B';
        numberGrade = '3';
    }
    else if (score <= 100)
    {
        letterGrade = 'A';
        numberGrade = '4';
    }
    
    cout << " " << letterGrade << endl;
    cout << " " << numberGrade << endl;
}

main()
{
    convert();
    convert();
    convert();
    convert();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not have logged the grades in `convert()` function. The name of the function should reveal it's purpose, and as the name suggests, the function simply "converts" the number. So it shall not do the logging part. You could have done the logging part in `main()`.

You should try the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

pair<char, char> convert(int score)
{
    char letterGrade, numberGrade;
    
    else if (score <50)
    { 
        letterGrade = 'E';
        numberGrade = '0';
    }
    else if (score <60)
    {
        letterGrade = 'D';
        numberGrade = '1';
    }
    else if (score < 70)
    {
        letterGrade = 'C';
        numberGrade = '2';
    }
    else if (score < 80)
    {
        letterGrade = 'B';
        numberGrade = '3';
    }
    else if  (score <=100)
    {
        letterGrade = 'A';
        numberGrade = '4';
    }  
    
    return make_pair(letterGrade, numberGrade);
}

int main()
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
       int score;
       cout << "Please enter a score." << endl;
       cin >> score;
       if (score<0 || score >100)
       {
           cout << "Test scores must be between 1-100. " << endl;
           continue;
       }
       sum += score;
       auto converted = convert(score);
       cout << " " << converted.first << endl;
       cout << " " << converted.second << endl; 
    }
    cout<<"The average grade is: " sum/4 <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```